# list items of HashMap in a list view, android

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

I am writing an android application to display the nearby locations, I have two activities; one to show locations on the map and the other is to list them in a ListView.

in the first activity, I store the information about each place in a hashMap, these information includes: place name, place longitude and latitude, this is the code to store info in a HashMap:

// Clears all the existing markers
            mGoogleMap.clear();

```
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Getting a place from the places list
            //HashMap<String, String>
            hmPlace = list.get(i);

            // Getting latitude of the place
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

            // Getting longitude of the place
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

            // Getting name
            String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

           // listP[i]=hmPlace.get("place_name");
            Log.d("places=",hmPlace.get("place_name"));

            // Getting vicinity
            String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);



            // Setting the title for the marker.
            //This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Linking Marker id and place reference
            mMarkerPlaceLink.put(m.getId(), hmPlace.get("reference"));
        }  
    }
```

in this activity I have a button to direct me to the second activity which must list the nearby places in a ListView; this is the code for the button:

```
public void list_airports(View v)
        {
            Intent intent;
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.list_items:

                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), List_airports.class);
                intent.putExtra("com.example.dashboard_our.hmPlace",hmPlace);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
            }
```

in the second activity I do this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_airports);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        HashMap<String, String> places1=(HashMap<String, String>) extras.getSerializable("com.example.dashboard_our.hmPlace");


         final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);



        list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < places1.size(); ++i) {

            list.addAll(places1.values());

            }
            }
```

but it just prints the first place's information many times, How could I solve this problem??

This is the rest of the code:

```
final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                  int position, long id) {
                final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0)
                    .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                        list.remove(item);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        view.setAlpha(1);
                      }
                    });
              }

            });
          }



          private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

            HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<String> objects) {
              super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
              for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
              }
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
              String item = getItem(position);
              return mIdMap.get(item);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
              return true;
            }




          }


          public static void printMap(Map mp) {
                Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                   // System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
                    list.add(pairs.toString());
                    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
                }
            }
```

this is the code of the 'do in background' which parses the Json and return places:

```
/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
        private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

            JSONObject jObject;

            // Invoked by execute() method of this object
            @Override
            protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

               // List<HashMap<String, String>>
                places = null;
                PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

                try{
                    jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                    /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
                    places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
                }
                return places;
            }
```

where places:

```
  List<HashMap<String, String>> places;
```

Comment: by _"prints the first place's information"_ you mean print it in the log or display in the list view? If in the list view.. then post your adapter code. if print in the log, then something wrong with the way you serialize the data

Comment: You should use list.get(i) in order to get the hashmap value.

Comment: @AmulyaKhare in the listView, I will edit my question

Comment: @HAL9000 how could I use list.get(i)?? I want to add the values from the HashMap to the list, and then put them in ListView

Comment: @roa.tah can you tell me what do you see in the `ListView`, like what values you see (name? lat? long?) (maybe put a screenshot).. the name or the lat or everything? do you have a `getView()` method?

Comment: @AmulyaKhare I get lat,long, name of one place and printed many times

Answer (score 0):

To get values from hashmap to a List :

```
        Set keySet = hashMap.keySet();
        Iterator it = keySet.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) it.next();
            Object value = (Object) hashMap.get(key)
            // do stuff here
            yourListArray.add(value);
        }
```

From the list to the ListView :

- At first pass the List in the constructor of your Adapter, in GetView() use mList.get(position) to initialize the cells.
- If you want to add or delete cells in the listview use a setter (public void setmList(List list)) then do adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the datas.

Comment: No change!! It still prints the first place's info

Comment: I tried to help in accordance to want i understood of your issu. Maybe your question is not clear enough :) Is it that you want to put hashmap values in a list and then pass it to the listview before doing a refresh ? (one advice : you should separate more your code and use better indentation) And somethimes using BaseAdapter is simple..

Comment: I have a HashMap, I want to get the values from it and put them in list in order to view them in a listView, my problem is: I just get one element and it is printed 5 times

Comment: Ok, the method i gave you works (i use it) try to do some log to see what is happenning to your values

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `hmPlace` is a single `HashMap` containing information about one location. When you pass value from first activity to the seconfd you do:

```
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), List_airports.class);
intent.putExtra("com.example.dashboard_our.hmPlace",hmPlace);
startActivity(intent);
```

This means you are only passing one `HashMap` object containing one location information. This probably the reason you see the behavior.

**Update**

Based on your above updated. You `places` variable has a list of all places. (hopefully).

So you should do something like:

```
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), List_airports.class);
intent.putExtra("places",places);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now in the second activity get the list of places using this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placeList = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_airports);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(bundle!=null)
    {
        placeList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) bundle.getSerializable("places");
    }
}
```

And now, modify the adapter to use this new list which has `HashMap` items. You will have to  modify your adapter for that.

Comment: As i mentioned, this is a possible reason. Could you verify that what I have said is correct? See if `list` in the second activity has all locations? Also I asked you for screenshot.. that will help

Comment: I answered your question above :)

Comment: please let me know if you have any further info that I need. Otherwise I can't help you at the moment..

Comment: I don't know what info you may need !!
I think what you have said is right, hmPlace contains the info of one place.
I will post a code that parses the Json and get the places

Comment: how about you post the first activity and let me have a look.. maybe i shall try to compile and see.

Comment: the first activity is more than 600 lines

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42185/discussion-between-amulya-khare-and-roa-tah)